# jQuery validation addmethod - how to return defferent language messages?

Tags: javascript, jquery, validation, jquery-validate

I have a custom method for **bassistance** [jquery validation plugin](http://bassistance.de/jquery-plugins/jquery-plugin-validation/) that returns a message but the problem is that I would like to return default plugin message in different languages by simply adding the localization file as always. My question is how to connect to those default messages inside custom addmethod? Here is the code:

```
jQuery.validator.addMethod("notEqual", function(value, element, param) {
   return this.optional(element) || value !== param;
}, "This field is required");   //replace this with default language messages
```

Hope I could explain the issue. Thank you.

Comment: "default plugin message in different languages by simply adding the localization file as always" - Can you tell us which plugin you're using exactly, it's not obvious.

Comment: http://bassistance.de/jquery-plugins/jquery-plugin-validation/

Comment: Could you load your validation messages into variables depending on which localization file you have included? The you could pass the variable in to the validator as the message.

Comment: The error message should be inside <input /> element, `<input data-val="true" data-val-notEqual="This is my error message"/>`, and then you will populate the error message from server side (where you are applying culture)

Comment: Thank you guys but @MMM provided perfect solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you just need to call `$.validator.messages`:

```
jQuery.validator.messages.required
```

So:

```
jQuery.validator.addMethod("notEqual", function(value, element, param) {
   return this.optional(element) || value !== param;
}, jQuery.validator.messages.required);
```

Comment: Open `messages_##.js` (where ## is the loc code) to view available messages

Comment: wont let me do it that fast, will have to wait another 5 minutes =)